# Кнопка Вверх-Вниз с запоминанием - проблема в отслеживании позиции

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть кнопка вверх-вниз с запоминанием и возвращением к месту, откуда была сделана прокрутка вверх.

Прокрутка вверх работает, но прокрутка вниз к месту откуда был сделан скролл вверх не работает. никак не могу найти причину, никаких ошибок нет. забавно, браузер походу игнорит событие от слова -совсем))

```js
;(function($){var h=$.scrollTo=function(a,b,c){$(window).scrollTo(a,b,c)};h.defaults={axis:'xy',duration:parseFloat($.fn.jquery)>=1.3?0:1,limit:true};h.window=function(a){return $(window)._scrollable()};$.fn._scrollable=function(){return this.map(function(){var a=this,isWin=!a.nodeName||$.inArray(a.nodeName.toLowerCase(),['iframe','#document','html','body'])!=-1;if(!isWin)return a;var b=(a.contentWindow||a).document||a.ownerDocument||a;return/webkit/i.test(navigator.userAgent)||b.compatMode=='BackCompat'?b.body:b.documentElement})};$.fn.scrollTo=function(e,f,g){if(typeof f=='object'){g=f;f=0}if(typeof g=='function')g={onAfter:g};if(e=='max')e=9e9;g=$.extend({},h.defaults,g);f=f||g.duration;g.queue=g.queue&&g.axis.length>1;if(g.queue)f/=2;g.offset=both(g.offset);g.over=both(g.over);return this._scrollable().each(function(){if(e==null)return;var d=this,$elem=$(d),targ=e,toff,attr={},win=$elem.is('html,body');switch(typeof targ){case'number':case'string':if(/^([+-]=)?\d+(\.\d+)?(px|%)?$/.test(targ)){targ=both(targ);break}targ=$(targ,this);if(!targ.length)return;case'object':if(targ.is||targ.style)toff=(targ=$(targ)).offset()}$.each(g.axis.split(''),function(i,a){var b=a=='x'?'Left':'Top',pos=b.toLowerCase(),key='scroll'+b,old=d[key],max=h.max(d,a);if(toff){attr[key]=toff[pos]+(win?0:old-$elem.offset()[pos]);if(g.margin){attr[key]-=parseInt(targ.css('margin'+b))||0;attr[key]-=parseInt(targ.css('border'+b+'Width'))||0}attr[key]+=g.offset[pos]||0;if(g.over[pos])attr[key]+=targ[a=='x'?'width':'height']()*g.over[pos]}else{var c=targ[pos];attr[key]=c.slice&&c.slice(-1)=='%'?parseFloat(c)/100*max:c}if(g.limit&&/^\d+$/.test(attr[key]))attr[key]=attr[key]<=0?0:Math.min(attr[key],max);if(!i&&g.queue){if(old!=attr[key])animate(g.onAfterFirst);delete attr[key]}});animate(g.onAfter);function animate(a){$elem.animate(attr,f,g.easing,a&&function(){a.call(this,e,g)})}}).end()};h.max=function(a,b){var c=b=='x'?'Width':'Height',scroll='scroll'+c;if(!$(a).is('html,body'))return a[scroll]-$(a)[c.toLowerCase()]();var d='client'+c,html=a.ownerDocument.documentElement,body=a.ownerDocument.body;return Math.max(html[scroll],body[scroll])-Math.min(html[d],body[d])};function both(a){return typeof a=='object'?a:{top:a,left:a}}})(jQuery);
 
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn, {
 toplinkwidth: function(){
  totalContentWidth = jQuery('#content').outerWidth(); // ширина блока с контентом, включая padding
  totalTopLinkWidth = jQuery('#arrows-updow').children('a').outerWidth(true); // ширина самой кнопки наверх, включая padding и margin
  h = jQuery(window).width()/2-totalContentWidth/2-totalTopLinkWidth;
  if(h<0){
   // если кнопка не умещается, скрываем её
   jQuery(this).hide();
  } else {
   if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= 1){
    jQuery(this).show();
   };
  }
 }
});
 
jQuery(function($){
 var topLink = $('#iupdown');
 // если вам не нужно, чтобы кнопка подстраивалась под ширину экрана - удалите следующие четыре строчки в коде
 topLink.toplinkwidth();
 $(window).resize(function(){
  topLink.toplinkwidth();
 });
 $(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() >= 1) {
   topLink.fadeIn(300).children('a').html('наверх').parent().removeClass('bottom_button').addClass('top_button');
  } else {
   topLink.children('a').html('вниз').parent().removeClass('top_button').addClass('bottom_button');
  }
 });
 topLink.click(function(e) {
  if($(this).hasClass('bottom_button')){
   // при нажатии на кнопку «Вниз» переходим туда, где прекратили чтение
   $("body").scrollTo( pos + 'px', 500 );
  } else{
   // определяем и запоминаем координаты того места страницы, откуда был совершен переход наверх
   pos = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
   $("body,html").animate({scrollTop: 0},500);
  }
  return false;
 });
});
```

```html
<div class="btn-updow" id="iupdown"><a href="#top">кнопка</a></div>
```

помогите справиться с гадом))